# compute mouse position within video with object-fit:contain

Tags: css, html, html5-video

I am trying to convert a mouse event to pixel coordinates within a video. By pixel coordinates, I mean coordinates relative to the original video resolution.

My video element has `object-fit: contain`, which means that the top left corner of the video is not necessarily located at position `(0,0)`, as this picture shows:

[image]

If I click on the top-left corner of the white section in this video then I want to get `(0,0)`, but in order to do this I need to discover the offset of the video content (white area) relative to the video element (black border).

How can I recover this offset?

I am already aware of `width`, `height`, `videoWidth`, and `videoHeight`, but these only let me account for the scaling, not the offset.

Answer (score 0):

The offset can be deduced. I think this kind of code should do the trick:

```
if(videoHeight/height > videoWidth/width){
    scale   = videoHeight/height;
    offsetX = (videoWidth - width*scale)/2;
    offsetY = 0;
}
else{
    scale   = videoWidth/width;
    offsetY = (videoHeight - height*scale)/2;
    offsetX = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also interested in getting the actual pixel positions from mouse or touch events when using `object-fit`, and this is the only result I found when searching. Although I suspect it is probably too late to be helpful to you, I thought I'd answer in case anybody else comes across this in future like I did.

Because I'm working on code with other people, I needed a robust solution that would work even if someone changed or removed the `object-fit` or `object-property` in the css

The approach that I took was:

1. Implement the `cover`, `contain` etc algorithms myself, just functions doing math, not dependent on the DOM
2. Use `getComputedStyle` to get the element's `objectFit` and `objectPosition` properties
3. Use `.getBoundingClientRect()` to get the DOM pixel size of the element
4. Pass the element's current `objectFit`, `objectPosition`, its DOM pixel size and it's natural pixel size to my function to figure out where the fitted rectangle sat within the element
5. You then have enough information to transform the event point to a pixel location

There's more code than would comfortably fit here, but getting the size of the fitted rectangle for cover or contain is something like:

```
  if ( fitMode === 'cover' || fitMode === 'contain' ) {
    const wr = parent.width / child.width
    const hr = parent.height / child.height
    const ratio = fitMode === 'cover' ? Math.max( wr, hr ) : Math.min( wr, hr )

    const width = child.width * ratio
    const height = child.height * ratio
    const size = { width, height }

    return size
  }

  // handle other object-fit modes here
```

Hopefully this gives others a rough idea of how to solve this problem themselves, alternately I have published the code at the link below, it supports all `object-fit` modes and it includes examples showing how to get the actual pixel point that was clicked:

https://github.com/nrkn/object-fit-math